# Scala cannot compile string literal

Tags: scala

I wonder why Scala doesn't compile the following code:

```
val bar = "p1"
val baz = "p2"
val str = s"foo=\"-param1$bar -param2$baz\""
```

I want variable "str" to be something like

```
foo="-param1p1 -param2p2"
```

And the compiler error is

```
value - is not a member of String
val string = s"foo=\"-param1$bar -param2$baz\""
                     ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's limitation of interpolated string literals. You can use the `s""" blah """` form to get enclosed double quotes.

To wit:

```
scala> val bar = "p1"
bar: String = p1

scala> val baz = "p2"
baz: String = p2

scala> val str = s"""foo="-param1$bar -param2$baz\""""
str: String = foo="-param1p1 -param2p2"
```

Comment: It seems that `s"foo=\"-param1$bar -param2$baz\""` matches syntax in sip-11.

Comment: It does seem that way, but if you hunt around in the JIRA you'll find it's acknowledged as a bug, but a "Won't Fix," if I recall correctly.

Comment: They will add `$"` eventually; you can also `s"${'"'}"`. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476